# Notation for eigenvalues

Tags: notation, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there a specific notation for eigenvalues? specifically, I'd like to write:
$$m\equiv \text{smallest eigenvalue of }H$$
I've seen some sources write this as: $H\succeq mI$, where "$\succeq0$" means the matrix is positive semi-definite, but it seems a bit convoluted.

Is there a simpler, more accepted way to write this?

Comment: I don't believe there's a standard notation for the smallest eigenvalue.  I assume you mean smallest in absolute value?  And it wouldn't necessarily be unique so that's also problematic.

Comment: What's wrong with saying something like "let $m$ be the smallest eigenvalue of $H$"? Provided that this makes sense, of course (see Gregory's comment above)...

Comment: @ABC Please don't make purely cosmetic edits to old questions. That bumps them to the active queue but they are not really active, so waste the time of folks who follow that queue.

Answer (score 3):

Normally one says something like "Let $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $H$ in non-decreasing order." or "Let $\lambda_1 \leq  \ldots\leq  \lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $H$."

Then, you just say $\lambda_1$.

Comment: I take this as "no".

Comment: Pretty much. Just stating the fact in words is a good way to go as well ("Let $m$ be the smallest eigenvalue of $H$) if you only need the smallest eigenvalue, as suggested in the comments to the original question